# How to deal with BOM in UTF-8 resource file

Tags: spring-mvc, globalization, resourcebundle

I have a resource file that is UTF-8 with a BOM. When the resource loader returns the first key/value pair the BOM is appended to the key string and thus the real key can't be matched. Should I just remove the BOM or is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: remove the BOM if you can

Comment: The BOM is optional in UTF-8. But optional is not the same as "can't be used." It should be hidden from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the resource file with NotePad++ and save it without BOM.